# Sencha Touch 2 Carousel with toolbar?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, carousel

Hi how i create a carousel with a toolbar, Would like to have the option to tap to switch views and also swipe to to switch views, here is my code , When I run this the xtypes inside the toolbar are not showing up in a toolbar ?

Thanks

```
Ext.define("NF.view.tablet.MainH", {
   extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
   requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],


   config: {
   tabBar: {
      hidden: true},    

    items: [

    {
        xtype : 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        title: '',
        layout:'hbox',
        items:[ 

               {xtype: 'home'} ,
               {xtype:'tablet-placesContainer'},
                {xtype:'tablet-About'},
               {text: 'contact'},
               { xtype: 'contactpage'},
                {xtype: 'home3'} ,
               ],

    },  



    {
    xtype:'carousel',
    layout:'fit',
    iconCls: 'home',
        items:[

        {xtype: 'home'} ,

        {xtype:'tablet-placesContainer'},

        {xtype:'tablet-About'},

        {xtype: 'gallery'},

        { xtype: 'contactpage'},

        {xtype: 'home3'} ,

        ]
   }]
   }
```

});

```
    When I run this the toolbar info is not showing up.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but maybe your best bet is to

1) Make each toolbar item a simple button with html for the name of the carousel item

2) Give the carousel a name

3) just have a tap event for each toolbar item that sets the correct active item:

```
Ext.define("NF.view.tablet.MainH", {
   extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
   requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],


   config: {
   tabBar: {
      hidden: true},    

items: [

{
    xtype : 'toolbar',
    docked: 'top',
    title: '',
    layout:'hbox',
    items:[ 

           {xtype:'button',text: 'home', handler:function(){Ext.getCmp('carousel_name').setActiveItem(0)}} ,
           {xtype:'button',text: 'places', handler:function(){Ext.getCmp('carousel_name').setActiveItem(1)}} ,
           ],

},  



{
xtype:'carousel',
id:'carousel_name',
layout:'fit',
iconCls: 'home',
    items:[

    {xtype: 'home'} ,

    {xtype:'tablet-placesContainer'},

    {xtype:'tablet-About'},

    {xtype: 'gallery'},

    { xtype: 'contactpage'},

    {xtype: 'home3'} ,

    ]
```

}]
   }